# How to store event in calender in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

```
 EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
 EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];
 NSString *trimmedString = [[arrDateList objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
 myEvent.title     = [d valueForKey:@"garden_name"];
 myEvent.startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimmedString];
 myEvent.endDate   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimmedString];
 myEvent.allDay = TRUE;

 [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
 NSError *err;
 [eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

I am using the above line of code but i cant store the event in calender...
please help me where i have mistake in line of code....
Thanks & regards 
Rahul Virja

Comment: Have you checked you are getting proper start and end date ?

Comment: Yah i get the start and end date proper....

Comment: I get this...EKEvent <0x84d94a0> {title = Caereuni; location = (null); calendar = (null); alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = (null); timeZone = (null)}; location = (null); startDate = 2012-07-28 18:30:00 +0000; endDate = 2012-07-29 18:29:59 +0000; allDay = 1; floating = 1; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)

Comment: For testing can you check with the future date event ? and are you getting id of store event? eg.,NSString *Eid=myEvent.eventIdentifier; You can get id after saveEvent called.

Comment: Do you get an error back? Please post the description of the error.

Comment: i can not get any of the error....

Comment: yes i get the eventidentifier... i get this type of id=818644E8-A590-4513-8853-E96196225D91:0A6505C0-DC15-48AD-B662-9484E23693F3

Comment: As you are getting identifier too. you are testing in device right ? If yes then it must show there.code is okay. don't know there might be some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code..

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[taskDetails taskStartDateTime]];

## if DEBUG

```
    NSLog(@"here is the task start %@",[taskDetails taskStartDateTime]);
```

## endif

```
    NSDate *end = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[taskDetails taskEndDateTime]];
    [dateFormatter release];
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = [taskDetails taskGottaDo];   
    event.startDate = date;
    event.endDate = end;
    EKAlarm *reminder = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-6*60*60];
    [event addAlarm:reminder];
    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    NSTimeInterval alarmOffset = -1*60;//1 hour
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];

    [event addAlarm:alarm];
    [eventStore release];

    NSError *err;
    BOOL saved = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

   // NSLog(@"here is the error %@",[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]);
    if (saved == YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@""
                                  message:@"Saved to calendar"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Right On!" otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
        [alertView show];   
        [alertView release];
    }
```